# Succinct way to print all lines up until the last line that matches a given pattern

Tags: linux, perl, shell, tail

I'm trying to find a succinct shell one-liner that'll give me all the
lines in a file *up until* some pattern.

The use case is dumping all the lines in a log file until I spot some
marker indicating that the server has been restarted.

Here's a stupid shell-only way that:

```
tail_file_to_pattern() {
    pattern=$1
    file=$2

    tail -n$((1 + $(wc -l $file | cut -d' ' -f1) - $(grep -E -n "$pattern" $file | tail -n 1 | cut -d ':' -f1))) $file
}
```

A slightly more reliable Perl way that takes the file on stdin:

```
perl -we '
    push @lines => $_ while <STDIN>;
    my $pattern = $ARGV[0];
    END {
        my $last_match = 0;
        for (my $i = @lines; $i--;) {
            $last_match = $i and last if $lines[$i] =~ /$pattern/;
        }
        print @lines[$last_match..$#lines];
    }
'
```

And of course you could do that more efficiently be opening the file,
seeking to the end and seeking back until you found a matching line.

It's easy to print everything as of the *first* occurrence, e.g.:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/,$p'
```

But I haven't come up with a way to print everything as of the *last*
occurance.

Comment: Your title says "all lines up until the last pattern" but your two example scripts print all lines from the last pattern to the end.  I assume it's the title that's misleading?

Comment: If the pattern will usually be present and near the end, you might want to consider [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ReadBackwards) (unshifting into a buffer until you reach the pattern or beginning of file).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a sed-only solution. To print every line in `$file` **starting with** the last line that matches `$pattern`:

```
sed -e "H;/${pattern}/h" -e '$g;$!d' $file
```

Note that like your examples, this only works properly if the file contains the pattern. Otherwise, it outputs the entire file.

Here's a breakdown of what it does, with sed commands in brackets:

- [H] Append every line to sed's "hold space" but do not echo it to stdout [d].
- When we encounter the pattern, [h] throw away the hold space and start over with the matching line.
- When we get to the end of the file, copy the hold space to the pattern space [g] so it will echo to stdout.

Also note that it's likely to get slow with very large files, since any single-pass solution will need to keep a bunch of lines in memory.

Comment: +1: That's mighty fancy sed handling. It's one line and does what the  OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively: `tac "$file" | sed -n '/PATTERN/,$p' | tac`

EDIT: If you don't have `tac` emulate it by defining

```
tac() {
    cat -n | sort -nr | cut -f2
}
```

Ugly but POSIX.

Comment: I don't have a `tac` binary.  Given that the OP didn't specify an operating system, it's probably best to offer solutions that will work across the board.

Comment: You can use `tail -r` in place of `tac`. Although this solution isn't quite what (the body of) the question is asking for. For that, you'd need `sed -n "1,/${pattern}/p"`.

Comment: @ghoti: Well, it seems you're not using GNU/coreutils. Apparently `tac` isn't POSIX. If you insist on POSIX, use `cat -n | sort -nr | cut -f2` instead of `tac` (Oh, we're getting ugly again!)

Comment: @RobDavis: `tail -r` isn't POSIX either, and not available on my Debian System. For the second part: True, title does not match body question. But please give the whole line, which would be `tac | sed -n '1,/PATTERN/p' | tac` (or tac replacement)

Answer (score 4):

Load the data into an array line by line, and throw the array away when you find a pattern match. Print out whatever is left at the end.

```
 while (<>) {
     @x=() if /$pattern/;
     push @x, $_;
 }
 print @x;
```

As a one-liner:

```
 perl -ne '@x=() if /$pattern/;push @x,$_;END{print @x}' input-file
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a simplification of your shell script:

```
tail -n +$(grep -En "$pattern" "$file" | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1) "$file"
```

It's substantially more concise because it:

- Uses tail's `+` option to print from the given line to the end, rather than having to calculate the distance from there to the end.
- Uses more concise ways of expressing command line options.

And it fixes a bug by quoting $file (so it will work on files whose names contain spaces).

Answer (score 3):

Sed's `q` command will do the trick:

```
sed "/$pattern/q" $file
```

That will print all the lines until it gets to the line with the pattern. After that, sed will print that last line and quit.

Comment: This does what the title and first line of the question suggest but not what the questioner actually wants, I think. He wants all the lines *after* and including the last line that matches a given pattern.

Comment: @RobDavis - You're right. I read the first paragraph, and thought _"Hey, this is simple"_. I'll probably have to come up with something with Awk

Answer (score 1):

This questions title and description don't match.

For the question's title, +1 for @David W.'s answer.  Also:

```
sed -ne '1,/PATTERN/p'
```

For question in the body, you've already got some solutions.

Note that `tac` is probably specific to Linux.  It doesn't seem to exist in BSD or OSX.  If you want a solution that's multi-platform, don't rely on tac.

Of course, just about any solution is going to require that your data either be spooled in memory, or submitted once for analysis and a second time for processing.  For exampel:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

tmpfile="/tmp/`basename $0`,$$"
trap "rm $tmpfile" 0 1 2 5
cat > $tmpfile

n=`awk '/PATTERN/{n=NR}END{print NR-n+1}' $tmpfile`

tail -$n $tmpfile
```

Note that my use of `tail` is for FreeBSD.  If you use Linux, you'll probably need `tail -n $n $tmpfile` instead.

Comment: You can use `tail -r` on OSX to get the functionality of `tac`.

Comment: That's true, but it's also not multiplatform as the `-r` option does not exist in Linux.  If I recommend against one, it would be hypocritical of me not to recommend against the other. :)

Comment: I understand and agree entirely - I was merely pointing out, mainly for any readers in the future, that if they want to use `tac` on OS X, they can use `tail -r` instead... rather than leaving your statement saying it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Davis pointed out to me what you ***said*** you wanted isn't what you really asked:

You said:

> I'm trying to find a succinct shell one-liner that'll give me all the lines in a file ***up until*** some pattern.

but then at the very end of your post, you said:

> But I haven't come up with a way to print everything ***as of*** the last occurance.

I've already gave you the answer for your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966036/368630). Here's a one line answer for your second question: Printing from a regular expression to the end of the file:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /'"$pattern"'/) { flag = 1 } if (flag == 1) { print $0 } }' $file
```

A similar Perl one-liner:

```
export pattern="<regex>"
export file="<file>"
perl -ne '$flag=1 if /$ENV{pattern}/;print if $flag;' $file
```

Comment: Except he wants the lines after the last occurrence of the pattern, I believe.

Comment: @RobDavis - You're right. Your [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8967705/368630) is the best. It's one line and platform independent.