# Print lines between two regex using sed

Tags: sed, unix

I have a text file which contains multiple sections and I want to print one of those sections.

Part of the file looks like

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

From this I want to retrieve all lines between `## Screenshots ##` and the starting of the next section. Here the next section is `## Changelog ##`, but it could be anything. So the only thing which we can depend on is that it will start with `##`.

From [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8967705/24949), I found the following code

```
sed -e "H;/${pattern}/h" -e '$g;$!d' $file
```

which I modified to

```
sed -e "H;/## Screenshots ##/h" -e '$g;$!d' readme.md
```

Now, it retrieves all lines starting from `## Screenshots ##`, but it prints all lines till the end of the file.

I then piped it to another `sed` like

```
sed -e "H;/## Screenshots ##/h" -e '$g;$!d' readme.md | sed "/^##/q"
```

But now it prints only

```
## Screenshots ##
```

Is there anyway I can print all lines in the screenshots section?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
awk '/pattern/{p=1;print;next} p&&/^##/{p=0};p' file
```

take the "Screenshot" as example:

```
kent$  awk '/^## Screenshot/{p=1;print;next} p&&/^##/{p=0};p' file
## Screenshots ##

1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4
```

**EDIT** add explanation

```
awk '/^## Screenshot/{p=1;print;next} : if match pattern, set p=1,print the line,read next line,(stop processing following scripts)
p&&/^##/{p=0}                         : if p==1 and match /##/ again (next section), set p=0
;p' file                              : if p==1, print the line
```

**sed only**

```
sed -n '/## Screensh/,/##/{/Scree/{p;n};/##/{q};p}' file
```

**EDIT2** add explanation to sed cmd

```
-n                 -> not print
'/## Screen/, /##/ -> match range, I guess you knew it already
{                  -> if in this range
    /Scree/        -> and line matches /Screenshot/
        {p;n};     -> do print line, and read next row (skip doing rest processing)
    /##/           -> if line matches "##"
        q;         -> quit, we have done all printing
    p              -> if we come to here, print the line
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly write a brief line explaining how it works? I am able to follow part of it, but not fully.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I am choosing the other answer since I already had subsequent commands in `sed`. I have upvoted the answer though :)

Comment: @Sudar, ok you didn't mention the requirement of sed. or (sed only). any way, I added a sed only solution, without piping to head.

Comment: Nice `sed` solution. You can omit the curly braces around the `q` though.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the pipe :) I started writing it, but then it became something else. So i took the cheating approach :), instead of correcting the regex, just piped it to head

Comment: @Kent Sorry I was not clear about `sed`. I have accepted your answer now. One thing I noted is that your `sed` solution doesn't work in Mac. It works only in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Sudar I am not familiar with bsd/mac sed. I have gnu sed. I think your ubuntu has installed gnu sed too. You could take a look the man page, if some options are needed for bsd sed. I have 0 experience with mac...

Comment: @Kent Can you kindly explain the last part of the `sed` command. I tried referring the man pages, but still couldn't figure it out. Once I understand it, I will try to port it to bsd sed.

Comment: I tried run "<long running command> | <grep something> | <awk as above>  in a bash script and pipe the awk output to "while read line", I was not getting any output. I ended up doing print $0 inside awk. Anyone know why this works? "while read line" works ok till grep, but breaks after awk.

Answer (score 11):

`sed -n '/## Screenshots ##/,/##/p' readme.md`

This will start printing from `## Screenshots ##` till the next `##` is found. If you don't want the last `##` match, easiest is

`sed -n '/## Screenshots ##/,/##/p' readme.md |head -n-1`

Answer (score 6):

#### awk

This can be done more easily and more generically with `awk`:

```
awk '/^##/ { p-- } /^## Screenshots/ { p=1 } p>0' infile
```

If you only want one section, this will do:

```
awk '/^##/ { p=0 } /^## Screenshots/ { p=1 } p' infile
```

Output:

```
## Screenshots ##

1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4
```

*Explanation*

```
/^##/ { p-- }               # subtract one from the section counter
/^## Screenshots/ { p=1 }   # set section counter if current line has Screenshot 
p>0                         # print line if section counter greater than 0
```

#### sed

```
sed -n '/^## Screenshots/,/^##/p' infile | sed '$d'
```

Comment: Can you kindly write a brief line explaining how it works? I am able to follow part of it, but not fully.

Comment: @Sudar: I added comments to each section of the awk script.

Comment: thanks for the comments. And sorry for the confusion. I wanted only lines in the screenshot section.

Comment: @Sudar: in that case set the section counter to 1.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I am choosing the other answer since I already had subsequent commands in `sed`. I have upvoted the answer though :)

Comment: @Sudar: I see, I've added a two tier sed solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to filter out sections of a file where they can [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102851/how-to-check-if-a-macro-exists-in-an-object-file-in-c#comment91426929_10102889). I'm talking about output of `dwarfdump`. Each section starts with a name, like `.debug_macro`, or `.debug_line`. For example,

```
.debug_info
...
.debug_macro
...
.debug_line
...
.debug_macro
...
```

Here's the script (run with `-n`):

```
:l1 /^\.debug_macro/ {  # loop that prints a section
    # pattern space holds current line
    # hold space holds contents of current .debug_macro section
    #     up until current line
    $ { p; q }          # print and quit if at the last line
    h                   # initialize hold space (copy first line of the section)
    :l2 n               # loop that adds lines to hold space
    $ {                 # if at the last line...
        /^\./ {         # if at the beginning of a section
            /^\.debug_macro/ {   # if at the beginning of .debug_macro section
                H                # add line to hold space
            }
        }
        /^\./ ! H       # add line if not at the beginning of a section
        x; p            # print hold space
        q               # quit
    }
    /^\./ ! {           # if not at the beginning of a section...
        H               # add line to hold space
        b l2            # branch to :l2
    }
    x; p; x             # print hold space
    b l1                # branch to :l1
}
```

Output:

```
.debug_macro
...
.debug_macro
...
```