# Pipe lines between two regex through another command

Tags: awk, unix

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16587218/24949) that I recently asked.

I have a text file which has multiple sections. Part of the file looks like this.

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

I want to transform this file, such that all the lines of the file are present in the transformed file and the lines in the `screenshot` section are passed through another command, before being added to this file.

So the transformed file might look like

```
3. line 3
4. line 4

## Screenshots ##

1. modified 1
2. modified 2
3. modified 3
4. modified 4

## Changelog ##

3. line 3
4. line 4
```

I have the following command which prints only the lines in the `screenshot` section. (From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16587661/24949))

```
awk '/^## Screenshot/{p=1;print;next} p&&/^##/{p=0};p' readme.md
```

I tested my command by piping to the output of the above command and it works.

But now I want to print the other lines of the file untouched as well. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can easily modify the text as you want in `awk` (eg, convert "line" to "modified"), just do it directly:

```
awk '/^## Screenshot/{p=1} p{gsub( "line", "modified")} p&&/^##/{p=0}; 1' readme.md
```

If it is not feasible to do the replacement in awk for some reason, you can simply have awk break up the output and then join:

```
awk '/^## Screenshot/{f="file2"} 
    f=="file2" && /^##/{f="file3"} 
    {print > f}' f=file1 readme.md
... # Now perform the desired filter on file2
cat file1 file2 file3 > final_output  # Concatenate results
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for writing about splitting up file as well.

Comment: One small thing. In your example code you forgot to close the quote at "modified" string