# Sed remove from match until match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to remove parts of a file starting from a match (including the first match) and until the second match (excluding the second match). My file looks like this, from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587218/print-lines-between-two-regex-using-sed/16587661):

```
3. line 3
4. line 4
## Screenshots ##
1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4
## Changelog ##
3. line 3
4. line 4
```

From the answers of [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587218/print-lines-between-two-regex-using-sed/16587661) I have taken a `sed` command that outputs from `## Screenshots ##` until `4. line 4`, just before `## Changelog ##`. However, I would like to remove that section from the file.

To clarify, I only know that the next section will start with `##`, it could be `## foobar ##` for all I know :)

I have tried to replace the print commands by delete commands like so

```
sed -e '/## Screensh/,/##/{/Scree/{d;n};/##/{q};d}' file
```

but that did not work because it stops output after the second match, `## Changelog ##` in this case (because of the quit command). I have also tried to use a regex character class to match anything but a `#` character like `sed -n '/## Screenshots ##[^#]*/p'` but that only prints `## Screenshots ##`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
sed '/## Screenshot/,/##/{/Screenshot/d;/##/!d}'
```

That's it - delete everything between two matches, including the first but not including the last. If you know that the section ends with '## Changelog ##' it becomes just

```
sed '/## Screenshot/,/##/{/## Changelog/!d}'
```

Comment: Isn't your solution also a simpler version of the script to output the section if used with -n? As in: `sed -n '/## Screenshot/,/##/{/Screenshot/p;/##/!p}'`?

Comment: Not sure if I should re-ask, but I'd actually like to use bash variables inside the expression. This means changing the quotes to double-quotes and this, in turn, makes `!` a character I need to escape for my shell, but `sed -i "/## Screenshot${var}/,/##/{/Screenshot${var}/d;/##/\!d}" file` complains about `\` being an unknown command :(

Comment: I have played with it for a bit and it seems sed is ok to have an argument which consists of several concatenated strings: `sed "something"'!'"something else"` worked for me.

Comment: *Edit: thanks!* Oh, got it, just have to use double and single quotes in the same command, according to http://superuser.com/a/301330/31926

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` version:

```
sed '/## Screenshot/,/## Changelog/d' file
3. line 3
4. line 4
3. line 3
4. line 4
```

And an `awk` version

```
awk '/## Screenshots/{f=1;next} !f; /## Changelog/{f=0}' file
3. line 3
4. line 4
3. line 3
4. line 4
```

Comment: or `awk '/## Screenshots/,/## Changelog/{next}1' file`

Comment: @jaypal I have not seen this before, thanks.  Normally I try to avoid the `/to/,/from/` in `awk` since it limits some the for other test. For simple task `,` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '/## Screenshots ##/,/## Changelog ##/d' test.txt
3. line 3
4. line 4
3. line 3
4. line 4
```